# Angular library: make local TypeScript dependency part of the compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, ng-packagr

I have a Angular lib inside a Nx workspace...

The lib consumes code from another **local** lib for some shared TS code.

The shared libs path is defined in the tsconfig paths setting:

```
"paths": {
    "@myOrg/sharedLib": ["libs/shared/src/index.ts"],
}
```

Code is imported from the shared lib via TypeScript imports like this.

```
import {someUtilFn} from '@myOrg/sharedLib'
```

The question is:
How can I make sure, that the code of the shared lib, becomes part of the built / compiled Angular library?
Till now the built Angular library only contains its own code, skipping external dependencies. The user of the Angular lib (who installs it e.g. via npm) will be forced to install the shared lib was well.

Because the Angular lib is going to be installed via npm... it would be possible to publish the shared lib as well and make it a dependency / peer dependency of the Angular library.
But I want to avoid that the user of the Angular lib can import code from the shared lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated answer

only application flatten the dependencies, but libraries doesn't there is a discussion here https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4829 but the nx teams seems not doing it

so your option is to publish the common library to npm, and add it as a dependency in your package.json not peer dependency

this will make sure when the user download/update the main library it will download the other one as well

the difference between them is that peer dependency is something the end-user will be using and also your library, but a dependency is something that the user won't be using

Comment: Hi Robert, my question is maybe not so clear :)

The goal is: the built Angular library - which is published to npm - should contain also the code of the shared lib.

Comment: I edited the question for a little bit more clarity.

Comment: @spierala can you please share a repo?

Comment: there is indeed a repo.

Currently on a separate branch: https://github.com/spierala/mini-rx-store/pull/203

shared code is in @mini-rx/common. @mini-rx/signal-store is using the shared lib code.

Comment: you are right, in your example you need to release `@mini-rx/common` as well, you can add it as a dependency not as a peer-dependency so it's downloaded and updated automatically with your oher packages

Comment: there is a way to make it included, I will explore and let you know

Comment: it seems not possible with libraries, updated my answer

Comment: thank you @Robert for checking! Currently I opted to use @mini-rx/common as a peer dependency. 
I also tried dependency but then common also lands in the node_modules at top level.

Comment: @spierala I think there are two benefits for it not being a peer dependency, 1. even though it's in the top level the IDEs won't index it, so the user won't have it in the autocomplete, 2. when your user needs to update he will only update one and it will automatically update the other since you have bumped the dependency in the `package.json` without having to explicitly do it, another point is that while npm install it in the top level I blieve pnpm won't, so it depends on the package mananger